# Как объединить рекурсию в lisp по этому коду

Tags: алгоритм, рекурсия, lisp, common-lisp

Всё ещё разбираюсь с рекурсией в лиспе, вот сразу задача

> Написать функцию, имеющую два аргумента x и y, где y – список, x –
> атом. Функция должна удалять из Yy все элементы, совпадающие с x.
> **Исходный список может быть многоуровневым.**

В общем и целом, у меня получилось написать такой код.

Ниже приведена рекурсивная функция, которая делает одноуровневый список из многоуровневого.

```
(defun toSameLvl (lst)
    (cond
        ((null lst) nil)
        ((atom (car lst)) (cons (car lst) (toSameLvl (cdr lst)) ) )
        (T (append (toSameLvl (car lst)) (toSameLvl (cdr lst))))
    )
)
(toSameLvl `((1 2 4) 1 2 4 2 (1 2 (1 2 3) 3)))
>>>(1 2 4 1 2 4 2 1 2 1 2 3 3)
```

Ниже приведена рекурсивная функция, которая удаляет заданный элемент из одноуровневого списка.

```
(defun deepRemove (x y)
    (cond
        ((null y) nil)
        ((not(atom x)) nil)
        ((= x (car y)) (deepRemove x (cdr y)))
        (T (cons (car y) (deepRemove x (cdr y))))
    )
)
(deepRemove 0 `(0 2 3 4 0 2 0 4 2 0))
>>>>(2 3 4 2 4 2)
```

**Но, что самое важное, нужно написать это всё используя одну функцию, а не две как делал я, не используя функционналы, циклы и функции присвоения!**

Напишите, пожалуйста, код, как это сделать грамотно, с меня, как обычно взамен ничего ツ

Comment: Зачем вы решили делать список одноуровневым? Разве есть такое требование в постановке задачи? Всё, что вам нужно - изменить `deepRemove` так, чтобы к элементам `x` типа `list` применялась функция `deepRemove`

Comment: @PakUula Сможете написать код, как это сделать? Я не понимаю как встроить одно в другое, согласен функция приведения к одноуровнему списку тут лишняя(я писал её лишь для того что бы разобраться как работает рекурсия, на всякий случай её сюда прикрепил).

Comment: Покажите ваш код `deepRemove`

Comment: @PakUula в вопросе он есть, второй листинг это функция deepRemove которая работает пока что только с одноуровневыми списками

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё, что вам нужно - применить `deepRemove` к `(car y)` если этот элемент не является атомом.

```lisp
(defun deepRemove (x y)
    (cond
        ((null y) nil)
        ((not(atom (car y))) (cons (deepRemove x (car y)) (deepRemove x (cdr y))))
        ((= x (car y)) (deepRemove x (cdr y)))
        (T (cons (car y) (deepRemove x (cdr y))))
    )
)
(deepRemove 0 `((0 2 3 4) 1 2 0 (0 2 0) 4 2 0))
```

Результат `((2 3 4) 1 2 (2) 4 2)`

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень пом0огли мне, только я думаю что вместо `cons` в проверке которую вы добавили, нужно написать `append`, потому что если дупустим список будет `(0 0 0)` то он по сути должен удалиться, но в случаае с `cons` вместо него возвращается просто `NIL`, а с `append` всё корректно. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @StillStealSteel NIL - это правильный ответ. Вы удалили все нули, остался пустой список